# Hibernate/JPA: Unexpected cascade on merge

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

Hibernate Version: 4.0.1.Final / JPA

Hello,

i want to merge a detached table. After executing entityManager.merge() all child tables are selected from the database.

The child tables are annotated in the parentTable with:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parentTable")
```

There is no cascade annotation. I do not want to cascade the child tables on merge.
How can i disable the cascading on merge?

```
@Transactional
public void save() {
    entityManager.merge(parentTable); //cascades child´s here
}
```

Only the child tables are re-selected that have been fetched previously.

Thanks
tak3shi

Comment: Did you find some final solution to block merge cascade?

Answer (score 0):

All cascades are disabled by default. If you do not want to cascade anything, simply do not add cascade attribute to @OneToMany annotation.

On the other hand, if you want to cascade everything else, except merge, use following:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
           mappedBy = "parentTable" 
           cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, 
                      CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE})
```

Maybe there is some other problem which have nothing to do with cascading merge operation. In that case showing entities and how code that creates and merges them would be useful.

Comment: i do not use any cascade. I have also tried to set only CascaType.DETACH but it still cascades on merge.

Comment: <code>@Transactional
    public void save() {
        entityManager.merge(parentTable); //cascades child´s here
    }</code>

Comment: What makes you think that there is merge happening as result of this operation? Which changes are actually performed to the entities in list? Most likely you see queries that are connected to state of relation between parent and it's children and that has nothing to do with merge. Saving changed relationship between parent and childrens is part of saving (in this case via merge operation) state of parent.

Comment: I have checked this in the debugger. Only the child tables are re-selected that have been fetched previously.

Comment: This doesnt work for me.  All relationships are automatically cascaded when any detached object is merged.  I am using EclipseLink.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ For EclipseLink make sure that Weaving is working.